# SQL Server Database "default" tables

Tags: sql-server

When I add a new database to our dev server (using SSMS), it automatically creates 5 tables.

These are copies of application tables that already exist in another database.

I assume this is some recent SQL Server feature I don't know about where tables can be marked as 'common' or some such, and so get added automatically to new databases.

But how can I stop it happening?

For the avoidance of confusion, this database is not scripted, it is created directly from the SSMS GUI (right-click Databases > New Database)

(moved from StackOverflow)

Comment: Check out the [model database](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388(v=sql.120).aspx) from system databases. Does it contain the tables too?

Comment: Yes the same tables - I assume that's the cause?

Comment: Yes, `model` is "model" database that is used as a source for every next database created.

Comment: Wow I never knew that (only been using SQL Server since version 6.3)

Comment: The feature has certainly been there since at least SQL Server 2005 (possibly earlier), though.

Comment: The model database feature has been around since SQL Server 4.21 (and before when it was Sybase).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens (based on the discussion in comments) because the tables exist in the `model` system database. As [per the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186388(v=sql.120).aspx) (my emphasis):

> If you modify the model database, **all databases created afterward will
>   inherit those changes**. For example, you could set permissions or
>   database options, or **add objects such as tables**, functions, or stored
>   procedures. File properties of the model database are an exception,
>   and are ignored except the initial size of the data file.

As a solution, dropping the tables from `model` will stop this phenomenon.

Comment: MIght be worth adding that there are some exceptions, like `TempDB`  recreation after server restart. In that case, `TempDB` uses all own file properties, including initial size of data files.